# Custom NSTableHeaderView does not overlap cells when scrolling

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to create a custom `NSTableHeaderView` with a minimal style.

This is my current code:

```
public class RoundedTableHeaderView2 : NSTableHeaderView
{
    private let dividerHeight: CGFloat = 6.0
    
    public override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        // Bottom Line
        NSColor.secondaryLabelColor.set()
        let path = NSBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = .lineWidth / 2.0
        path.move(to: NSPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.bounds.height - .lineWidth))
        path.line(to: NSPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height - .lineWidth))
        path.stroke()
        
        guard let tableView = self.tableView else { return }
        
        // Columns
        for index in 0 ..< tableView.numberOfColumns
        {
            let column = tableView.tableColumns.at(index)
            
            let basicString = column.headerCell.stringValue
            let alignment = column.headerCell.alignment

            let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paraStyle.alignment = alignment
            
            let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11.0, weight: .semibold)
            
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font : font,
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paraStyle,
                .foregroundColor : NSColor.secondaryLabelColor,
            ]
            
            let textBounds = TextUtilities.measureSize(basicString, NSSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), font)
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: basicString, attributes: attributes)
            
            let frame = tableView.rect(ofColumn: index).insetBy(dx: 8.0, dy: textBounds.height / 2.0)
            attributedString.draw(in: frame)
            
            if index == 0 { continue }
            
            // Draw column dividers.
            self.drawDivider(frame)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Helper
    fileprivate func drawDivider(_ frame: NSRect)
    {
        NSColor.secondaryLabelColor.set()
        
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: NSRect(x: frame.minX - 8.0, y: self.bounds.height / 2.0 - self.dividerHeight / 2.0, width: .lineWidth, height: self.dividerHeight))
        
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Which produces the following result:

[image: Result]

I quite like the result, however, if I start scrolling, the content of the `NSTableView` overlaps the header view. I have tried to add a custom background color, but the content still overlaps the header.

[image: Cells overlapping NSTableHeaderView]

I tried using a custom NSTableHeaderCell instead of a custom NSTableHeaderView, but the result is the same. Here is the code of my cell:

```
final class CustomTableHeaderCell : NSTableHeaderCell
{
    override init(textCell: String)
    {
        super.init(textCell: textCell)
        self.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)
    {
        // skip super.drawWithFrame(), since that is what draws borders
        self.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }

    override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)
    {
        let titleRect = self.titleRect(forBounds: cellFrame)
        self.attributedStringValue.draw(in: titleRect)
    }
}
```

Changing the background color to something like red draws the color but the cells still overlap the header cells.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are the cell views in front of the header view? How did you add a background color?

Comment: The cell views are indeed in front of the header view, I don't know why. In the `draw` function, I added the following code for drawing a background color: `NSColor.red.setFill(); NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).fill()`